# Undefined Variable in code for information to be submitted into the table

Tags: php, variables

been working hard on making a forum on my website and came across some problems with my variables for the information that I am submitting into my table. Please dont down vote me or close this because I am this question has been answered because I looked at other posts and nothing helped me. Here is my code:'

```
<?php include 'header.php';

$host="XXXXX"; // Host name 
$username="XXXXX"; // Mysql username 
$password="XXXXX"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="XXXXX"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="XXXXXX"; // Table name 

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);


mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

if(isset($_GET["submit"])){
$topic=$_POST['topic'];
$detail=$_POST['detail'];
$datetime=date("d/m/y h:i:s"); 
}
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(topic, detail, datetime)VALUES('$topic','$detail','$datetime')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if($result){
echo "Successful<BR>";
echo "<a href=gen.phpView your topic</a>";
}
mysql_close()
?>
```

error:
Notice: Undefined variable: topic in /home/XXXX/XXXX/gen.php on line 21

Comment: line 21 is$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(topic, detail, datetime)VALUES('$topic',      '$detail','$datetime')";

Comment: It's your form's method.

Comment: how can i fix this? by the way, your awesome Fred you answered an earlier question of mine your great!

Comment: Thanks, glad I was able to help. Now, this `if(isset($_GET["submit"]))` and `$_POST` tells me that you may have a conflict. If your form method is POST, then you'll need to change that to `if(isset($_POST["submit"]))`, however if it's GET then you'll need to change all your `$_POST` to `$_GET` which will explain the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're sending the data via POST, I tell you this because you're evaluating also a GET here:

```
if(isset($_GET["submit"])){
    $topic=$_POST['topic'];
    $detail=$_POST['detail'];
    $datetime=date("d/m/y h:i:s"); 
}
```

Also, you should evaluate if you're not getting any null values via the post or simply declare the variable as an empty string before the if statement.

Have you echoed a var_dump of the $_POST array?

Comment: can you please clarify?

Comment: Try this before the if statement and please post me the result so I can make my answer more clear:

echo var_dump($_POST);
exit;

Comment: All that happens when I add your code is I receive an error saying Undefined index.

Comment: So the problem is that you're not getting any data via POST, try using $_GET instead of $_POST

And as S.Pols said, you need to execute your query inside the if statement scope, otherwise your variables don't exist in the same scope as $sql, so it cannot use them.

Comment: Try this:

if(isset($_GET["submit"])){
$topic=$GET['topic'];
$detail=$GET['detail'];
$datetime=date("d/m/y h:i:s"); 

$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(topic, detail, datetime)VALUES('$topic','$detail','$datetime')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if($result){
echo "Successful<BR>";
echo "<a href=gen.phpView your topic</a>";
}
mysql_close()
}

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `$_GET['submit']` variable exists? The error is that the variable `$topic` is not set. What happens if you try this:

```
$topic = "test";
$detail = "test";
$datetime = date("d/m/y h:i:s", time()); 

if(isset($_GET["submit"])){
$topic=$_POST['topic'];
$detail=$_POST['detail'];
$datetime=date("d/m/y h:i:s"); 
}
```

Does it inserts test?

Comment: You are also perform an insert query when the `$_GET['submit']` doesn't exists. You need to put the query inside the if statement.

Comment: Alright this made me receive a message saying "Successful" how can I get around this undefined error?

Comment: Put the query and the `if($result)` inside the `if(isset($_GET["submit"]))` statement. Be sure when you are submitting your form the `$_GET["submit"]` variable exists by add it into your forms action (action="gen.php?submit=submit") or change it to `$_POST["submit"]` if your submit button named 'submit'.

Comment: And be sure you have 2 input fields named 'topic' and 'detail'.

Comment: Can you tell me what to insert and where I should insert it? I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to say.

Comment: Try the code of Kurtz, that's what i meant!